# Start my app from an event in Android calendar?

Tags: android, android-activity, calendar

Is it possible to create a calendar event that can open my app? The alarm sounds and it then goes something like this: "Event blah. Would you like to start MyApp?" -> Yes -> MyApp's main activity launched.

Is this possible?

(Targeting Android 2.2)

Comment: No. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I think you can finish by uri scheme. here is the links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919165/opening-android-app-from-calendar