# Opening Android App from Calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

The app I'm working on needs to be able to create events in a chosen Calendar and then when the user views these events in their calendar viewing app it offers an option to return to the my app to view more information about it and the data related to it.

Using [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) I'm able to create the events and I store the Uri to the event for later use/removal but I haven't found a good way to open my app from these events in a calendar viewing app.

The 2 options that I have considered are to include a custom URL in the event description that when clicked will be caught by an intent filter in my app (e.g. myapp://event/1000) or I could set the [CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE and CUSTOM_APP_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE) values from CalendarContract when creating the event.

My problem with the first option is that I don't think I can guarantee that the calendar viewing app will correctly treat my custom URL as a link and let the user click on it (didn't work in Google calendar on my tablet). The 2nd option looks more promising but I haven't been able to find much documentation explaining how to use it.

Does anyone know how to properly do this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please provide info.  about  implementation of how you provided an option to return to app from Calendar ?

Comment: Hi Woestman  ! Could you please provide us information about  your implementation mechanism for return to the app from Calendar to view more information about it.

Answer (score 13):

If targeting Jelly Bean (API 16+) is acceptable then using `CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE` is the best solution. When adding the new calendar event, you just need to fill the [`CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE) and [`CUSTOM_APP_URI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#CUSTOM_APP_URI) fields (with your package name and an URI identifying the event respectively):

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Check stackoverflow.com");
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, beginTime.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endTime.getTimeInMillis());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_URI, "myAppointment://1");

getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Then you need to specify as part of AndroidManifest.xml (as [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html#ACTION_HANDLE_CUSTOM_EVENT) explains) the Activity that will be called from the Calendar app to show the detailed view, e.g.

```
    <activity android:name=".ShowCalendarDetailActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.calendar.action.HANDLE_CUSTOM_EVENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/event" />
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>
```

`ShowCalendarDetailActivity` will be started when tapping on the button that appears, and will be passed an Intent with action `"android.provider.calendar.action.HANDLE_CUSTOM_EVENT"` and its URI will be the calendar item URI.

The custom URI you supplied is in the extras, with key `CalendarContract.EXTRA_CUSTOM_APP_URI`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String myCustomUri = getIntent().getStringExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_CUSTOM_APP_URI);

    ...
}
```

If you want to take a look at the code where the Calendar app builds this intent, see `EventInfoFragment.updateCustomAppButton()` in [`EventInfoFragment.java`](https://github.com/android-ia/platform_packages_apps_Calendar/blob/master/src/com/android/calendar/EventInfoFragment.java).

Comment: I did not get it to work yet, as no button to open the app shows up in the calendar. I only use an Intent (with CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE and CUSTOM_APP_URI in the extras), not the Calendar provider... should that also be possible or do I have to switch to Calendar Provider?

Comment: Hi @friday I haven't actually tested it but I've had other problems using intents instead of the content providers (for example, when adding contacts). So I wouldn't be that surprised if it didn't work... :/

Answer (score 4):

The first option you listed works fine on my Nexus S. I just tried it right now to make sure it was working coming from the default Google Calendar app.

In my case, I'm not intercepting `myapp://event/1000`, I'm intercepting an actual url more like `https://myspecialdomain.com/blahblah`. The browser starts to load, but before it has the time to load anything, it gets swapped out by my application.

I can show you my code tomorrow if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response (although I'm taking a while to respond).

I ended up using your suggestion for API levels below 16 and then using CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE and CUSTOM_APP_URI for API levels 16 or above. Although I was hoping there would be something like CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE that worked for lower API levels, I was glad to hear your suggestion works before I went through the work of implementing it.

Thanks!

Comment: @Stephan Im doing exactly as your suggestion and for some reason only the browser is opened. The same intent filter is working perfectly when clicking the same link from emails, tweets and whatsapp messages.

Comment: This is my intent filter. Any idea what's wrong here. <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="my.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/product/"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="www.my.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/product/"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>