# Open Cordova Android App from Calendar

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi I am using EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin in my ionic app to save calendar events.

What I want to achieve is when I go my calendar and click on that event I want to open my app. 
How to do that?

Comment: this answer is a good stating point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919165/opening-android-app-from-calendar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> You won't be able to override calendar functionality to direct to your
>   ionic application.You can only open your ionic app via custom links.

**How to open ionic application using custom url?**

Mobile applications made with Ionic Framework can leverage custom URL schemes by using a plugin [LaunchMyApp](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme)

Add the plugin into our project.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin.git --variable URL_SCHEME=ionicapp
```

Where the command **`--variable URL_SCHEME=ionicapp`**  is essential otherwise the plugin will fail to add.  Then you will be able to launch your application from any URL that starts like this:

```
ionicapp://
```

You could listen in your application for various URL paths and parameters and have your application do various things depending.  Add the following code globally:

```
var handleOpenURL = function(url) {
    alert("RECEIVED URL: " + url);
};
```

[Tutorial](http://mcgivery.com/using-custom-url-schemes-ionic-framework-app/)