# Add Deeplink to Calendar description

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-calendar

I want to add a deeplink to the description of a calendar event that my app adds. 
So basically, there is some information associated with the event that will change with time so it makes sense for the user to open the associated resource in the app. My deeplink looks like that example://resource/?somekey=somevalue

The calendar (probably also device specific, in that case on a galaxy s7) does not mark it as a link, which sucks for user experience.

Is there any way to make it a clickable link other than using a standard format as "http://experience.com/resource/?somekey=somevalue" (which the calendar seems to recognize) ? I dont want to make it look like a web resource as it isnt.

I already tried wrapping it in html tags but that didnt work out.

Suggestions? :)

Comment: Annoyingly, when I add the link with html tags such as <a href="example://resource">Click here</a> the calendar seems to interpret the html as it only displays "Click here" - however, it is not clickable. Wtf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening Android App from Calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919165/opening-android-app-from-calendar)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Back then I didnt find a way to fix it, seemed like a bug in the calendar app but as I said that might have been specific to the OS version or even the device. Glad you found a solution that works for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and if someone is looking for the answer.. That's how I get it done.

- First of all, you need to add  in your manifest (activity to open if user click in link).

  ```
  <activity
          android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">

      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>

      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "myapp://home” -->
          <data android:scheme="myapp"
                  android:host="home" />
      </intent-filter>

  </activity>
  ```
- When create an intent to calendar or to create event inside app (ContentValues), in Description option (param CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION), create string like this:

Kotlin:

```
val description = "<div>This is the description</div>" +
            "<div><a href=\"myapp://home\">myapp://home</a></div>";
```

Java:

```
String description = "<div>This is the description</div>" +
            "<div><a href=\"myapp://home\">myapp://home</a></div>";
```

An then add this in your description param.

Ex.:

- Create intent to open calendar, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents

  `intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);`
- Add in ContentValues to create event inside app, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event

  `contentValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);`