# Open app from default Calendar's Event description?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use `google calendar api` and adding `events` to it:

```
    /**starting code for adding event */

             event = new Event().setSummary("Meeting with employees")
                    .setLocation("Rehman Trade Center, Sargodha Pakistan")
                    .setDescription("Our team is going to organize a Meeting to discuss the Architecture")
                    .;
            DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2017-11-28T09:00:00-07:00");
            EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                    .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                    .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
            event.setStart(start);

            DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2017-11-28T17:00:00-07:00");
            EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
                    .setDateTime(endDateTime)
                    .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
            event.setEnd(end);



            EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[]{
                    new EventAttendee().setEmail("xyx@gmail.com"),
                    new EventAttendee().setEmail("abc@gmail.com"),
                    new EventAttendee().setEmail("axc@gmail.com"),

            };
//            event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));

            event = mService.events().insert("primary", event).execute();
```

I read from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919165/opening-android-app-from-calendar/46342992#46342992) that we can do this using

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_URI, "myAppointment://1");
```

but don't found any way to add `CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE` and `CUSTOM_APP_URI` through `google calendar api`.
I appreciate your help. Thanks

example of what i want to achieve.
[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [CalendarContract.EventsColumns documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html) to start with.

> ```
> protected static interface CalendarContract.EventsColumns
> ```
>
> Columns from the Events table that other tables join into themselves.

From the summary there, you will find the implementation of `CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE` and `CUSTOM_APP_URI`

> [CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE)
>
> ```
> String CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE
> ```
>
> The package name of the custom app that can provide a richer
>   experience for the event. See the ACTION TYPE
>   [`ACTION_HANDLE_CUSTOM_EVENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html#ACTION_HANDLE_CUSTOM_EVENT) for details.
>
> [CUSTOM_APP_URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#CUSTOM_APP_URI)
>
> ```
> String CUSTOM_APP_URI
> ```
>
> The URI used by the custom app for the event.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE. you need to use two options CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE and CUSTOM_APP_URI.

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CUSTOM_APP_URI, "myAppointment://1");
```

Comment: hmm its ok dear

Comment: I think Google broke \ removed this functionality from the Google Calendar app.  My app did make use of this functionality and it worked great until it didn't.  It still works if you install the AOSP calendar app but something Google have done in the updates to their app has broken it or they've just quietly removed the functionality.  I can't find any way to verify this.  I've "reported it" from within the app many a time but what good does that do - none apparrently.